# How precise class names should be?

Tags: linked-data, rdf

For example if our database is about the European Union, is calling the class containing countries inside the EU `Country` descriptive enough, even though it's not supposed to contain countries outside of the EU?

Comment: this is more of a semantics/programming question than a question about open data.

Comment: It's recommended not to overburden IRIs with semantics, but something like `EU_Country` loks fine to me. This also would help to distinguish this class from classes in other ontologies in case of import etc. However, another relevant recommendation is to make  URIs persistent. From this point of view, something like `EU_Member` would be better.